# How does require work when calling node module directly?

Tags: node.js

When calling a node module directly, e.g. `$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d`, how is the module aware of how to handle any `require` functions?

I understand how the `require` function works, but I'm confused where it is defined.

I had assumed that using something like `$ npm start` would give context to handle `require`, but how does Node get involved (and define how to handle `require`) when the module is called directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the module directly, you're calling an executable that got installed as part of a package.

That executable runs a full Node interpreter, with the contents of the executable file as the script.

Basically, it's similar to running this on the command line:

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```